# Como salvar minhas queries (strings sql) no arquivo de log no Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Meu problema é o seguinte, como registrar as queries(a string sql gerada) no meu arquivo de log. Sei que existe uma função para isso, só que não quero ter que chamar esse cara em todos os meus métodos do meu Model.

Minha dúvida é, como eu poderia fazer para resolver esse problema de um forma mais simples?

Pensei nos hooks, mas pelo que pude ver não conseguiria criar um hook para acessar um Model.

Answer (score 2):

Para salvar um Log de todas as SQL (com teste estabelecidos ele traz as `SELECT` somente).

Como seria:

Vai no seu arquivo de configuração `application/config/config.php` e na chave ***enable_hooks*** coloque `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE`;

Também dentro de `application/config` no arquivo `hooks.php` coloque o seguinte código:

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(     // 'post_controller' indicated execution of hooks after controller is finished
    'class' => 'Db_log',             // Name of Class
    'function' => 'logQueries',     // Name of function to be executed in from Class
    'filename' => 'db_log.php',    // Name of the Hook file
    'filepath' => 'hooks'         // Name of folder where Hook file is stored
);
```

Agora crie um arquivo em `application/hooks` com o nome de `db_log.php` com o seguinte código:

```
class Db_log {

    function __construct() 
    {

    } 

    function logQueries() 
    {

        $CI = & get_instance();     
        $filepath = APPPATH . 'logs/Query-log-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.php';            
        $handle = fopen($filepath, "a+");     
        $times = $CI->db->query_times;    
        foreach ($CI->db->queries as $key => $query) 
        { 
            $sql = $query . " \n Execution Time:" . $times[$key];    
            fwrite($handle, $sql . "\n\n");
        }     
        fclose($handle);            
    }     
}
```

Pronto, logo após a primeira execução será gerado um arquivo de ***log*** por data, dentro da pasta `application/logs` armazenando todas as suas ***SQL***.

***Referencia e direitos autorais ao site:*** [JIGAR JAIN - Logging/Saving all DB queries in Codeigniter](http://jigarjain.com/blog/saving-all-db-queries-in-codeigniter/)

Existe também o [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) dessa configurações: [Codeigniter - Log all DB Queries in Log File](https://bitbucket.org/jigarjain/codeigniter-log-all-db-queries-in-log-file/src), se quiser clonar o repositório.

Comment: Gostei dessa implementação. Mas engraçado que o atributo 'queries' está retornando um array vazio.

Comment: Então eu também implementei @Mathdesigner47 e funcionou e primeira. O seu log está habilitado assim `$config['log_threshold'] = 4;` no arquivo config.php?

Comment: Está sim. Mas o lance todo é que esse cara '$CI->db->queries' está vazio.

Qual versao do CI você conseguiu implementar?

Comment: `"codeigniter/framework": "^3.0"` essa é a versão.